# Comparison/diff tool for the files in static resources with in eclipse

Tags: static-resources, subversion

Is there any tool which compares the differences between the previous file and the current file in the static resources. Static resources have many files and many people are working on it. We need a diff tool so each dev can compare the code and merge the changes it from eclipse .

Comment: Are you using any source control at all? Are the static resources binary files? We use SVN but you need to be careful with certain components such as Profiles, which change a lot.

Comment: Yeah we are using github. It shows the diff between all the files so that we can merge. While coming to the static resources it has multiple files so tracking is difficult in zip/resources files.

Comment: You may want to update the question to include that information. I read your question as you are looking for code version control but actually you want something that will compare the files within a static resource